# Json response not generated as expected using @JsonCreator andd @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, spring, annotations, jackson

I am using JDK 1.6 , Jackson 2.0.5 , Spring 3.0.3 and using jackson annotations to serialize and deserialize json response.

```
public class MyDate extends java.sql.Date{

  private static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  private String dateString;

  @JsonCreator
  public MyDate(@JsonProperty("dateString") String date){
        super(simpleDateFormat.parse(date).getTime());
        dateString = date;
  }

  public String getDateString(){
        return dateString;
  }
  private final setDateString(String date){
        // .....
  }
}
```

I am getting json response message like 1417977000000 , but it should be like 12/08/2014.
Do I need to write anything else also ?

I tried to follow [Jackson wiki page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureCreators) article.

EDIT:

On basis of discussion with @Sotirios Delimanolis I tried JsonValue annotation on getter method and it worked.

```
  @JsonValue
  public String getDateString(){
        return dateString;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your type is a `java.sql.Date` which is a `java.util.Date` which is considered special for Jackson. By default, it writes dates (instances of type `java.util.Date`) as their timestamps. You can disable this with

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

or the corresponding configuration for your version of Jackson.

This, however, will give you something like

```
"2014-12-08T08:00:00.000+0000"
```

It will not use your `SimpleDateFormat`. You can register a `DateFormat` with the `ObjectMapper` like so

```
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

---

The best solution would be to use composition over inheritance. Do not extend `java.util.Date` directly or indirectly.

Comment: Let me explain problem in composition , my Class has a variable of type java.sql.Date now in my application I use date format MMddyyyy , which is not the default of java.sql.Date. So I have to change Date format before I send json response and receive json response. So I created a custom class with my custom Date Format. To customize serialization I am trying to use @JsonCreator

Comment: I think all classes which are of type java.util.Date are not considered special , because when I used JsonValue annotation on my getter method I got desired json format. only problem is JsonValue doesn't help in deserialization.

Comment: @Vipin That's a whole other scenario, though. `@JsonValue` identifies your getter as the single producer of a value, which is a `String`.

Comment: I am new to jackson , may be I am not able to understand your point.

Comment: @Vipin Note the [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html): _Marker annotation similar to XmlValue that indicates that results of the annotated "getter" method (which means signature must be that of getters; non-void return type, no args) is to be used as the **single value** to serialize for the instance_. Jackson won't serialize your `MyDate` instance, it will use its `@JsonValue` annotated getter to serialize the returned value, which is a `String`.

Comment: I agree with this. What do you think about @JsonCreator , why it is not working in my case?

Comment: @Vipin `@JsonCreator` is for deserializing. Your problem is with serializing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66514/discussion-between-vipin-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: I was not aware of it that @JsonCreator is only for deserializing. I want to use annotation based approach , so I am planning to create Serilizer and Deserializer classes and then will use JsonSerialize and JsonDeserialize annotations on top of class.

Comment: Please suggest if it can be done using composition or any other better approach.

Comment: Can I use JsonValue for serialization and JsonCreator for deserialization both in same class?

Comment: @Vipin Ok, slow down. My answer explains what you asked in your question on how to get `"12/08/2014"` instead of `1417977000000`. If that's not what you're looking for, please edit your question or ask a new one. I've kind of gotten lost on what you're looking for now.

Comment: This could be solution but I need annotation based approach so don't want to try it.

Comment: @Vipin There's no pure annotation based approach. Sure you can use a `@JsonSerialize` but you'd need to write your own `JsonSerializer`. So either you do that or you configure your `ObjectMapper`. Alternatively, but this will require that you show exactly the JSON you want to generate for anyone to help you, you could stop extending `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a general solution, you can always set format per property

```
public class DateStuff {
     @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd,HH:00", timezone="CET")
     public Date creationTime;
}
```

For more information please read here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

Edit:

As a side note

> (aka "Please do NOT use java.sql.Date, ever!")
>
> Although Jackson supports java.sql.Date, there are known issues with
>   respect to timezone handling, partly due to design of this class. It
>   is recommended that this type is avoided, if possible, and regular
>   java.util.Date (or java.util.Calendar) used instead. If this is not
>   possible, it may be necessary for applications to convert these dates
>   using java.util.Calendar and explicit timezone definition.